# The QMainWindow is not activated after been called by the QDialog

Tags: python, pyqt5

When I run this code. The mainwindow named as the NextWindow is not activated and it is behind the QDialog which calls it. I cannot control the second window. I have worked on similar code before and it is possible to call Qmainwindow from a QDialog. I have followed the same method but I don't know why this cannot work.

Basically the code is just try to use one window to call another. The code is reproduced from the PyQt-Videos-Examples/QtResponsiveGUIThreading/hasher_threaded.py. The original code works well but what I want to do is to add another Qdialog to call the MainWindow. The issue is that about the Qthread method. It works fine with the QMainWindow but if I use QDialog, then the issue of QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running would appear.

The code is shown below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc

from pathlib import Path
from hashlib import sha1


def recursive_hashes(path):
    """Generate name and SHA1 hash of all files under the given path"""
    if path.is_file():
        sha1_obj = sha1()
        try:
            with open(path, 'rb') as handle:
                while True:
                    data = handle.read(8192)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    sha1_obj.update(data)
            sha1_hash = sha1_obj.hexdigest()
        except PermissionError:
            sha1_hash = 'Permission Denied'
        yield (str(path), sha1_hash)
    elif path.is_dir():
        try:
            for child in path.iterdir():
                yield from recursive_hashes(child)
        except PermissionError:
            yield(str(path), 'Permission Denied')
    else:
        yield (str(path), 'Not a file or dir')

class Worker(qtc.QObject):

    hashed = qtc.pyqtSignal(str, str)

    @qtc.pyqtSlot(str)
    def hash_directory(self, root):
        hash_gen = recursive_hashes(Path(root))
        for path, sha1_hash in hash_gen:
            self.hashed.emit(path, sha1_hash)

class NextWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):

    hash_requested = qtc.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        """MainWindow constructor."""
        super().__init__()
        # Main UI code goes here
        form = qtw.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(form)
        layout = qtw.QFormLayout()
        form.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle('Second Window')

        self.file_root = qtw.QLineEdit(returnPressed=self.start_hashing)
        self.go_button = qtw.QPushButton('Start Hashing', clicked=self.start_hashing)
        self.results = qtw.QTableWidget(0, 2)
        self.results.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Name', 'SHA1-sum'])
        self.results.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(qtw.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.results.setSizePolicy(qtw.QSizePolicy.Expanding, qtw.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        layout.addRow(qtw.QLabel('SHA1 Recursive Hasher'))
        layout.addRow('File Root', self.file_root)
        layout.addRow('', self.go_button)
        layout.addRow(self.results)

        # Create a worker object and a thread
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker_thread = qtc.QThread()
        self.worker.hashed.connect(self.add_hash_to_table)
        self.hash_requested.connect(self.worker.hash_directory)

        # Assign the worker to the thread and start the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.start()
        #self.reject.connect(self.worker_thread.terminate)

        # Connect signals & slots AFTER moving the object to the thread


        # End main UI code
        self.show()

    def add_hash_to_table(self, name, sha1_sum):
        """Add the given name and sha1 sum to the table"""

        row = self.results.rowCount()
        self.results.insertRow(row)
        self.results.setItem(row, 0, qtw.QTableWidgetItem(name))
        self.results.setItem(row, 1, qtw.QTableWidgetItem(sha1_sum))
        print(name, sha1_sum)

    def start_hashing(self):
        """Prepare the GUI and emit the hash_requested signal"""

        # Clear the table
        while self.results.rowCount() > 0:
            self.results.removeRow(0)

        # Get the file root and validate it
        file_root = self.file_root.text()
        if not Path(file_root).exists():
            qtw.QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Invalid Path', 'The specified file root does not exist.')
            return

        # Emit the signal
        self.hash_requested.emit(file_root)
        #self.worker.hash_directory(file_root)


class MainWindow(qtw.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = qtw.QFormLayout()
        
        self.next_button = qtw.QPushButton('Next', clicked=self.next_button)
        layout.addWidget(self.next_button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("First Window")

    def next_button(self):
        self.dialog = NextWindow()
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The eventual outlook is as the image below

[image]

Where the First Window (QDialog) which calls out Second Window (QMaindwindow) still stays on the top of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when using [`exec_()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec) method then QDialog is in modal dialog as indicated in the docs and that it does not allow interaction with other windows until the dialog is closed:

> **int QDialog::exec()**
>  Shows the dialog as a modal dialog, blocking until
> the user closes it. The function returns a DialogCode result.
>
> **If the dialog is application modal, users cannot interact with any
> other window in the same application until they close the dialog. If
> the dialog is window modal, only interaction with the parent window is
> blocked while the dialog is open**. By default, the dialog is
> application modal.
>
> **Note:** Avoid using this function; instead, use open(). Unlike exec(),
> open() is asynchronous, and does not spin an additional event loop.
> This prevents a series of dangerous bugs from happening (e.g. deleting
> the dialog's parent while the dialog is open via exec()). When using
> open() you can connect to the finished() signal of QDialog to be
> notified when the dialog is closed.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Change `mw.exec_()` to `mw.show()`.